# OpenGL Texture filled by CUDA just contains old memory content

Tags: c++, opengl, cuda, interop, textures

i´m about to experiment with Cuda and OpenGL Interoperability. I render canvas geometry with OpenGL (a normal texture_2d) and i generated two texture_2d objects. The first texture_2d contains the original image data. It´s displayed fine and then i want to use this opengl texture as a source texture in cuda.

I want Cuda to perform a negative color image based upon the original image data (newColor = 1.f - originalColor) and store the result every frame in the second texture_2d object.

I tried the simpleCUDA2GL Example and this tutorial: http://3dgep.com/?p=2082 but all i see is the old texture memory content on the gpu, when i bind the second texture_2d object to my shader.

So i wanted to ask if somebody has a working (maybe cuda 5.5) example (as simple as possible, with opengl textures (not pbos)) which he could share or a detailed tutorial concerning my problem.

Comment: Show your work.  SO expects: "Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance. "  Voting to close.

Comment: No cuda error checking? Provide a complete code not snippets. Read sscce.org

Comment: Seems like no one does any error checking! Maybe CUDA should start throwing exceptions (at least in debug mode).

Comment: while debugging e was nothing else than cudaSuccess... and complete code would be about 1500 lines of code... so...

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can create a complete code around what you've shown here in less than 1500 lines.  I guess you haven't read sscce.org.  It's not asking for *your* complete  code, but a *short* complete code that will demonstrate the issue.  Yes, it requires work on your part.

Comment: Well... the rest is OpenGL context and window creation... but i guess you can close or delete the question now, thank you for your help

Comment: You can delete the question yourself if you have no intention of making it useful for others who might read it.

Comment: well... unsolved problems may not help anybody but...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution can be found there: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/659164/cuda-programming-and-performance/reading-and-writing-opengl-textures-with-cuda/

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  FYI, answers that are nothing more than an offsite link are [not recommended on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: Ya, thanks for the information, Just read your comment. Cui honorem, honorem! So you can surely imagine that, after all the "helpful contribution" on StackOverflow, I give a shit about what's not recommended on StackOverflow.